# How to insert a git branch between branches (and possibly rename) without affecting other users?

Tags: git, devops, branch, rename, git-history-rewrite

I have a repo that I share with other users, so I'd love a solution that minimizes what others have to do, if there's a way they can just pull the changes, I'd love that.

Here's my current git branching:

```
A--B---------F (master)
    \       /
     C--D--E (develop)
```

**Ideal goal**:

```
A (master)
 \
  B---------F (stable)
   \       /
    C--D--E (develop)
```

But if that's too hard to achieve, specially *without incurring complicated changes for everyone else* who already has a clone (because of renaming), then I wouldn't it mind it looking like this or similar:

```
A--B-------------F (master)
    \           /
     B'--------F' (stable)
      \       /
       C--D--E (develop)
```

**In short**: Ideally I'd love to create a *new* `master` that is empty, waiting for a release pull request from `stable`, and rename the *old* `master` to `stable`. The *new* `master` should be the parent of the *old* `master`.

Alternatively, if renaming complicates things for other people who have the repo cloned: I'd like the *current* `master` and `develop` to remain unchanged, but I want a new branch called `stable` between them so that stable `develop` commits get merged to `stable` in the future, and releasable `stable` commits are merged to `master`.

I guess there's a possibility that the alternative might end up looking more like this instead:

```
A--B---------F-------------M (master)
   |         |\           /
   |         | `---I-----L (stable)
    \       /     /     /
     C--D--E--G--H--J--K (develop)
```

Where G,H,J,K are new develop commits, I and L are merge commits from the stable H and K, and M is a releasable merge commit from L. This I assume I can easily do by branching off of `master` as `stable`, then making sure I'm merging from `develop` to `stable`, and `stable` to `master`, in the future. Or does git have a concept of parent-child relationship between branches?

Thank you in advance for any solutions!

EDIT: based on the answer given by torek, we could

1. checkout `develop` which won't change
2. create `stable` from `master`
3. create `main` from `master` at commit A

And it would look like this:

```
    ,---------------------M (main)
   /                     /
  /         ,-----I-----L (stable)
 /         /     /     /
A---------F     /     / (deprecated master)
 \       /     /     /
  B--C--D--G--H--J--K (develop)
```

After doing the following:

```
git checkout develop
git branch stable master
git branch main <first commit hash>
```

Answer (score 1):

The parent/child relationships in Git are tied solely to the *commits*.  Each branch name, in Git, is really just a label for the *last* commit in that branch (which may be a middle commit in some other branch: that's the case with `K` and `L` in your last example, for instance).

Branch names *can* be moved arbitrarily, so you could move your `master` back from `F` to `A` in your first example, after creating new name `stable` pointing to commit `F`:

```
git switch develop        # so that we're on one that doesn't move
git branch stable master
git branch -f master <hash-of-A>
```

The tricky part here is that everyone who has a clone of this repository will have their clone's `origin/master` remote-tracking name pointing to commit `F` too.  Those clones *will* update their own `origin/master` names on `git fetch origin`, so that they point to `A`, but if they have made *their own* `master` name pointing to existing commit `F`, *their* Git software will not move *their* `master` branch name just because `origin/master` moved—and their Git software will be reluctant to move *their* `master` "backwards", from `F` back to `A`, and will require some application of force.

Should you be inclined to rename `master` to `main`, this is a good time to do it: leave `master` alone, create new name `main` pointing to existing commit `A`, and tell people to run `git fetch`.  They will get a new `origin/main` pointing to `A`.  Tell them to create their own `main` in the usual way, if they wish—they don't *need* one if they're not using it.  Tell them the name `master` is now dead and will be removed and they should remove their own `master` once they have their commits on some other branch name(s) as necessary.

Remember that *every commit is 100% read-only*, so you can't change the existing `F` to have `F'` as a parent.  You can always make *new* commits, and those can contain whatever snapshot you like, and whatever list of parent hash IDs you like (so that they point backwards to any commit(s) that exist at the point you make the new commit).  Any *branch name* can point to any commit, but:

- each clone has *its own* branch names;
- Git is willing to *add commits to a branch* (by sliding the name "forwards" to new commits, as long as it doesn't lose old ones in the process, or by merging in new commits) at any time.  It requires applying force (as in `git branch -f` or `git reset`) to move a branch name "backwards" (the way the commit linkages actually go, from children backwards to parents).

So it's really easy to get other clones of this repository to *add on* stuff.  That happens automatically: people get the new commits whether they want to or not.  But it is hard to get people to retract branches: that takes manual work by each person.

---

Regarding your edit:

> ... And it would look like this:
>
> ```
>     ,---------------------M (main)
>    /                     /
>   /         ,-----I-----L (stable)
>  /         /     /     /
> A---------F     /     / (deprecated master)
>  \       /     /     /
>   B--C--D--G--H--J--K (develop)
> ```

It would eventually, once you've made more commits and made the merge `M`, yes.  (To get there from what you start with, you'd just run:

```
git branch main <hash-of-A>   # or git branch main master~2
git branch stable master
```

and on any GitHub-style servers, use the web interface to set up the "default branch" as `main` now, optionally also deleting `master` entirely.  To set the default branch, GitHub will run `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/main`, or whatever is equivalent in whatever software they're using.)

Comment: So if I perform a reset locally, there's no way to force that on others, I would have to create a revert commit, right? I assume that from what you said about going backwards and forwards.



Can you confirm that your proposed solution would look like the diagram I added as an edit to my question?



And if that's correct, can you edit your answer to include the diagram and a full list of commands to get there? (basically just add an alternative to your original answer where instead of ```git branch -f master <hash-of-A>``` you create a ```main``` branch from A

Comment: Also is it good practice to squash the merge when doing this kind of workflow? Otherwise all the unstable commits also become part of the stable and main branches

Comment: Yes: a revert (that undoes both commit `B` and the merge in `F`) added to `main` would get you a new commit with a snapshot that matches that in `A`. Unfortunately the *history* of that new commit would already include commits `B` and `F`, which means future merges would not bring back that work. So that's not a great idea. As for squash merges, I generally don't like them at all myself: they're only useful for reducing an entire branch to a single commit (and then killing off the other branch name). When that's what you want, it's great for that, but I almost never want that myself.